# does return 0 exit a program or exit a loop?

Tags: c, return

I have a question about `return` 0 in C:

```
void main()
{
    int i = 0;
    while(1)
    {
        switch(i)
        {
            case 1:
            case 2:
            case 3:
            case 4:
                i ++;
                break;
            case 5:
                return 0;
        }   
    }
}
```

will the return 0 exit the whole program or it will just exit from the while loop?

Comment: It will exit the `main` function.

Comment: should be `int main()`

Comment: Did you try it yourself? It would be easy to find out (and *then* ask a question if you don't understand the result of your debugging session).

Comment: I'm somewhat surprised this compiles... you declare `main` as `void`, and yet you return an `int`.

Comment: For historic reasons, it is possible to write return 0; to return from a function that has been declared as void

Comment: Try [this](http://goo.gl/Fpkd0w)

Comment: Is this not the kind of thing you can test yourself in 10 seconds?  Or easily google up the answer for?  I know S.O. welcomes all kinds of questions... but even the most self-answerable ones?

Comment: void main() with a return value is common in code From back in the DOS days.  An 8-bit return value was "required" by the OS (compiler would make it a 0 if you don't override) yet "void main()" is required by the language.  "int main()" isn't a true fit either since ints were *usually* 16-bits...  So, there was a compromise.  You could declare main either way, yet it always worked the same (allowing a 8-bit return and making it 0 if you fail to supply one).

Comment: @BLUEPIXY No, it should be `int main(void)`

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Recommended is not but is OK.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY That comment makes no sense to me. Remember that this is C. And `int main()` is very very different from `int main(void)`.

Comment: well, 6.5.3.4 The sizeof operator EXAMPLE 3

Comment: @DavidHeffernan see [n1256.pdf](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY It looks to me as though it is you that needs to get on top of this, if you don't know the difference between `int main()` and `int main(void)`

Comment: @DavidHeffernan so What mean "this is C" ?

Comment: In C++ `int main()` is correct, in C `int main(void)` is correct

Comment: It does not mean incorrect(or makes no sense) `int main()`  in C.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, `int main()` is correct, even for C, a definition of a function doesn't have to be a prototype. In a declaration `int main()` wouldn't be wrong either, only it would be underspecified. Even the C11 standard text still has two such examples with `()`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I cannot understand that comment, it is grammatically unclear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will return from the main method, which in this case, will exit the whole program.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, it will exit the `main()` function which will end the program. In general, a `return` statement will terminate a loop (that's normally `break` to *just* end the loop) by returning flow of control to a method caller; in the case of `main()` that is the operating system.

Comment: IMHO the `return` statement just returns to the caller without "terminating the loop".

Comment: Terminates the loop in the sense that the loop stops (because flow has returned to the caller).

Answer (score 1):

In your case,since `return 0` is placed in `main`,the program will exit. `return` will terminate the execution of the function and returns control to the calling function. When it is placed in `main` , it will exit the program. In order for `main` to return an `int`, use `int main` instead of `void main`. Also in C99 and above,you can't use `void main`.

Answer (score 1):

From the C-Standard 6.8.6.4/2

> A **return** statement terminates execution of the current function and returns control to
>   its caller.

As in the OP's code the "*current function*" is `main()` "*returning control to it's caller*" implies the end of the program.

Answer (score 1):

There are three basic "flow control" statements in C:

- `return` always leaves the currently executed **function** (optionally with a return value)
- `break` leaves the currently executed **loop**
- `continue` skips all remaining statements in the current **loop** and continues with the next iteration

In your case, `return 0` will terminate the current function `main()` thus exiting the whole program (the shell will see the result code 0).

Answer (score 0):

> A return statement causes execution to leave the current subroutine
>   and resume at the point in the code immediately after where the
>   subroutine was called, known as its return address.

In your program `main()` is the subroutine here and as `main()` is the program starts execution in C, so the exit from your `main()` will also be the exit from the program.

```
int getvalue()
{
    return 10;           //exit subroutine getvalue()
}

int main()
{
    printf("Value : %d\n",getvalue());   // get the return value from getvalue() and continue next
    printf("Next step after return\n");   
    return 0;                         // exit the main() subroutine
}
```

*Output:*

```
value : 10    
Next step after return
```

Here the program will print the return value *`10`* from `getvalue()` and also print *`"Next step after return"`* and then the `return 0` will cause the `exit` of the `main()` subroutine i.e program.

Answer (score 0):

the return keyword executes termination and current function and return the control flow to where it is called.
for ex:-
if we write return in user defined function it will not end the program but return the control to main function and terminates the user defined function
but in case if you have used return in main function it will terminate the main function which eventually end the program and return the control to operating system(caller).